# locate command - find only where whole word matches

Tags: terminal, locate

In a terminal window how can I use the command `locate` to only return results where the whole word is present.

For example, I was looking for all files related to GO lang. However, typing `locate go` returns everything from actual GO files to something like algorithm.php for example.

Is there a way to get this command to return only results where the whole word matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `locate` command which is part of [`mlocate`](https://fedorahosted.org/mlocate/) (a widely used implementation) accepts regular expressions, so you could do

```
locate -r '\<go\>'
```

Its documentation also says it has a `-w` option like the [GNU `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control) option for word-matching, but that does not function the same.  You can however
pipe the result from `locate` through `grep` with the `-w` option (words), e.g.,

```
locate go |grep -w go
```

grep also accepts regular expressions.  The `-w` option does not appear to be standard (see [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)), however it also is widely implemented, e.g., on [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/grep-1.html).

There is no POSIX document for `locate`; some implementations are notably less functional than others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for .go files, you can use `locate "*.go"` to find files that have that extension, instead of searching the full filename for the word 'go'.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was more just curious about how to `locate` a whole word in general, not specifically  finding .go files

Comment: Do you mean locating a file that is named `x` but has a wildcard extension? Or do you literally mean locating full words within a filename that are not separated by anything?